# Release of a C# application for Linux Ubuntu

Tags: c#, linux, ubuntu, .net-core

I'm writing a Telegram bot in C# in order to then host it on the server. When you try to release a project with the `dotnet publish -c release -r ubuntu.22.04-x64 --self-contained command`, an error appears as in the screenshot below
[image]

I tried using the `dotnet workload update` command to update the packages, but nothing worked. Projects that were created earlier and released using the same team can be released again, but this team has stopped working with new projects

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/sdk-errors/netsdk1083

Comment: Make sure on server you download the correct Core Version for linux x64.  See : https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download

Comment: As I understand it, this appeared as a result of upgrading the .NET version from later versions, and not as a result of file deletion/damage?

Comment: Are you familiar with the phrase _breaking change_, mentioned in the post below, and what it means in software development?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message states to visit https://aka.ms/netsdk1083 which redirects to [.NET SDK uses a smaller RID graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/sdk/8.0/rid-graph) which states:

> Projects that target .NET 8 or later versions now use a smaller,
> "portable" runtime identifier (RID) graph.
>
> **Previous behavior** The .NET SDK used a complex RID graph to determine
> assets when building or publishing a project.
>
> **New behavior Starting in .NET 8**, the .NET SDK uses a smaller graph
> consisting of only portable RIDs, for projects that target .NET 8 or a
> later version. This means that the SDK won't recognize
> version-specific or distro-specific RIDs by default.
>
> **Version introduced** .NET 8 RC 1
>
> **Type of breaking change**: This change is a behavioral change and can
> also affect source compatibility.
>
> **Reason for change**: The RID graph was costly to maintain and understand,
> requiring .NET itself to be distro-aware in a fragile manner. The .NET
> team and the community spend a non-trivial amount of time updating the
> graph and backporting such updates to previous releases. The long-term
> goal is to stop updating the RID graph, stop reading it, and
> eventually remove it. This breaking change is a step towards that
> goal.
>
> **Recommended action**: Use portable RIDs, for example, linux-<arch>,
> linux-musl-<arch>, osx-<arch>, and win-<arch>.
>
> If you need to revert to the previous behavior of using the old, full
> RID graph, you can set the *UseRidGraph* MSBuild property to true in
> your project file. However, the old RID graph won't be updated in the
> future to attempt to handle any other distros or architectures.

According to [.NET RID Catalog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/rid-catalog#linux-rids):

> **linux-x64**: (Most desktop distributions like CentOS, Debian, Fedora,
> Ubuntu, and derivatives)
>
> **linux-musl-x64**: (Lightweight distributions
> using musl like Alpine Linux)